# where to get R.id.container from in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am new to android. I have created a new android project selecting tabs as a template Eclipse implements tabs and pager itself. Each tab view has a fragment. Then I implemented ListView in a fragment.

Now when a list item is tapped, new view (fragment) should be open. To open a new fragment view on clicking list item, I need to give **R.id.fragment_container** to it. this id tells us on which container fragment view will be shown.

My Question is where should I get **R.id.container** as there is no container is defined with this id in the Main Activity. I have tried many things came in google like to add a layout (Relative/Linear) as well but it crashes and  also I have tried to give pager id as well but nothing happens.

Think i have some understanding problem with fragments. Any explanation/help specific to my case would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

R.id.fragment_container or R.id.container are the IDs of a View in your MainActivity's layout file.  Open that activity_main.xml (or whatever it is called) and add a container to hold your fragment.

You'll need to add the `android:id="@+id/fragment_container"` line to the View/Layout you choose.

Answer (score 1):

add andriod:id="@+id/id_name_".  in your fragment layout and call IT wherever u want

Comment: i have added it already there. But its still not picking it up.